# Is statistical inference just probability applied to the results from descriptive statistics?

Tags: probability, statistical-inference

I have that doubt due to I've been told that this branch of statistics infers from the data, understanding inferring as theestimate of a result, so I guess you use probability to make the estimates. But in case that is true, why is not pointed out that it is the result of the combination between statistics and probability?